# Passing variables to modal in ember

Tags: ember.js

I am following the Ember cookbook for rendering a route into a modal here: http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/. This works, but I am not sure how to pass variables to my rendered view.

Specifically I want to load a 'users/filters' route into the modal, which has access to a jobTitles array. This is defined in my application route simply as this.store.find('jobTitle'). The problem is that this does not seem to be accessible from the users/filters controller or template. The users/filters route doesn't seem to be run at all because I am using the render method as follows:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    openModal: function(modalName) {
      return this.render(modalName, {
        into: 'application',
        outlet: 'modal'
      });
    }
  }
});
```

How can I pass this into the rendered modal? Many thanks.

Comment: Could you .bind(this) to the render function? How about just storing the info on window.titleData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be to pass a controller to the modal rendering function:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        openModal: function(modalName, controller) {
            return this.render(modalName, {
                into: 'application',
                outlet: 'modal',
                controller: controller
            });
        }
    }
});
```

With the above code call the `openModal` hook in your route's template and pass the controller name (the name, not the controller itself) of the route to it. This way you should be able to access all properties of the controller.